# Can you add ASP.Net MVC 4 Intranet Template to existing empty project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package

I started a Visual Studio 2012 project by creating an asp.net MVC 4 empty project.   I would like to know if I can add the authentication membership provider, bundling, css, javascript that come packaged with the asp.net mvc 4 intranet site project template to my existing empty project without having to create from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new one. Copy classes from App_start folder, global.asax and web.config to your project

Comment: If I copy the Packages.config is there a command to have nuget redownload all the javascript and library dependencies?

Comment: nuget install packages.config

Comment: You can set also nuget restore on build http://blogs.4ward.it/enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio-and-tfs-2012-rc-to-building-windows-8-metro-apps/

Comment: pm> install-package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization  will add the WebOptimizations to the empty template.